# Simple limit in multi variable II

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**For $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ calculate (if it exists) the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{|x|^2}-1}{|x|^2+x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1}$$**
Solution: Let $f(x)=\frac{e^{|x|^2}-1}{|x|^2+x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1}$. Then $\frac{1}{f(x)}= \frac{|x|^2+x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1}{e^{|x|^2}-1} =\frac{|x|^2}{e^{|x|^2}-1}+\frac{x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1}{e^{|x|^2}-1}$.
When $x$ approaches $(0,0,0)$ the first term approaches 1. Thus we are left with evaluating the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1}{e^{|x|^2}-1}$$
How shall I proceed?

Comment: If the limit exists, if you go to $0$ for any two ways, it must be result the same value do $x=(x_1,0,0)$ and check the value of limit, Then use $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition with the value previusly calculated

Comment: Could you give a hint how to use epsilon-delta in this case? Not sure how to do it with exp-function.

Comment: You can use $|(x_1,x_2,x_3)|_1=\max{|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|}$, since all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, if $f(x)$ converges for any norm, converges for all.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What is $|(x_1,x_2,x_3)|_1$? Should I substitute $x_i$ with $x_M=max(|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|)$?

Comment: Its other norm in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there are other thing to explain? please let me know

Comment: What do you mean with "other" norm? Also can you answer my second question?

Comment: Yes, a norm is a function who tell us the "distance" between two vectors, there exists a lot of norms, and if a function converges with one norm, it converges with all norms.Yes,  you can reemplace $|x|$ with $x_M=max(|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3|)$ or $(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2})$ and the limit must be the same

Comment: What other norms are you referring to? I think we only have Euclidean.

Comment: Here you have a list of norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29
and here a proof for the equivalence of all of them. Look this if and only if you know some basic Linear Algebra. http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_13/norms2.pdf

Comment: OK I do not see how to relate to any of those except for Euclidean. Why do we have to consider all norms in $\mathbb{R^n}$, isn't it enough with the Euclidean?

Comment: Yes, is enough with Euclidean, but sometimes other norms reduce the work a lot, but you can work with the norm you like

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the limit exists and equals 1. 
If we take the path $(x,y,z)=(t, 0, 0)$

$$L= \lim _{t \to 0} \frac{e^{t^2}-1}{t^2}= \lim _{t \to 0} \frac{2te^{t^2}}{2t}= \lim _{t \to 0} e^{t^2}=1 $$

we get the same result if we take the path $(x,y,z)=(t, t, t)$

to prove that the limit exists we can transform to polar co-ordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ , take the limit $ r \to 0^+$, and show that this converges to 1 regardless of any possible relation between the polar variables.

$$L=\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{e^{r^2}-1}{r^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+r\cdot f(\theta, \phi)} $$

where $f(\theta, \phi)$ is a sum of products of sin and cos functions so it is bounded ( I suspect we can prove that $|f(\theta, \phi)|<3$ )

$$|\lim_{r\to 0^+} r\cdot f(\theta, \phi)| \le \lim_{r\to 0^+} 3r =0 $$

it follows that

$$L=\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{e^{r^2}-1}{r^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+r\cdot f(\theta, \phi)}=\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{e^{r^2}-1}{r^2} \cdot \lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{1}{1+r\cdot f(\theta, \phi)} =(1)(1)=1 .$$

Comment: We are not allowed to use L'Hôpital's. 
Also I don't see how this concerns the limit I refer to in OP. Could you clarify how you went from the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ to $r,\theta,\phi$?

Comment: I believe it is fine to use L'Hospital once the limit has been reduced to a single variable limit.

Comment: I was thinking of spherical polar co-ordinates. $x_1=r \cos \theta, x_2 = r \sin \theta \cos\phi, x_3 =   r \sin \theta \sin\phi$

Comment: Did you do your calculations for $\frac{e^{|x|^2}-1}{|x|^2+x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1} $or $\frac{x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1}{e^{|x|^2}-1} $ ? Don't you get quite a nasty expression when transforming to polar or how did you simplify it so much?

Comment: the first way as it originally appeared. note that $|x|^2=r^2$ and $x_1^2x_2=r^3 \cos^2 \theta \sin\theta \cos\phi$ . you could use this to calculate $f(\theta, \phi)$ explicitly, but you could establish the bound on $|f|$ by noting that $|x_n| \le r$

Comment: Yes but there are 2 more terms ($x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1$), no?

Comment: that is correct, but they will both be proportional to $r^3$ - the expression for $f(\theta, \phi)$ will be quite ugly, but the critical thing is not to calculate it but to show that it is bounded.

Comment: Oh right because we are multiplying it with r. Now I understand your answer I think, thanks.